# Ubuntu 16.04LTS couldn't detect exterenal monitor

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I connect my laptop to the second screen, and tried to detect it by System Settings --> Display. However it didn't work.
I had check other questions.
Most of them purged nvidia and installed nvidia-375, but I had install nvidia-381.
Should I purge it and install nvidia-375 ?

I had tried on Windows 10, it could detect my screen.

In addition, I tried `sudo nvidia-xconfig`.
It worked for just a moment after reboot,
and it cause my resolution fixed at 640*360.

My laptop is `GL552VW`, with `nvidia gtx960m & ubuntu 16.04lts`

Sorry for my poor English.

Here is the output of xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
DP-1-1 disconnected
HDMI-1-1 disconnected
HDMI-1-2 disconnected
DP-1-2 disconnected
HDMI-1-3 disconnected
```